# SIGABRT - App trying to find a deleted item

Tags: ios, sigabrt

I deleted a textfield called BLANK as it was not required. But now I get a SIGABRT in the line below:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

and this message:-

```
2012-04-26 15:37:24.208 SOA[2822:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Engine_Editor 0x6b528c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key BLANK.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13d9022 0x156acd6 0x13d8ee1 0x9d1022 0x942f6b 0x942edb 0x95dd50 0x24571a 0x13dadea 0x13447f1 0x24426e 0xea1fc 0xea779 0xea99b 0xf39bc 0xee818 0x30a565 0xf1857 0xf19bc 0xf19fc 0x459f4a 0x44e4d0 0x13dae99 0x2614e 0x264a0e 0x13dae99 0x2614e 0x260e6 0xccade 0xccfa7 0xcc266 0x4b3c0 0x4b5e6 0x31dc4 0x25634 0x12c3ef5 0x13ad195 0x1311ff2 0x13108da 0x130fd84 0x130fc9b 0x12c27d8 0x12c288a 0x23626 0x2a0d 0x2975)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

How do I remove the error?
I am new so please keep any answers simmple - thanks